# Why would Old Gods leave the Worldplanes alone?

Tags: magic, gods

In my universe's ancient past existed a duo of primordial gods, beings of anthropomorphism of the most barest of concepts. There was Oenui, architect of the universe, smith of its great form, and there was Paerii. Paerii, the mother of life, the mother of suns, and giver of life. Through the interplay of these beings, came a third, by the name of Dauh.

Dauh was the cautious, yet opportunistic primordial form of fate, disorder, chance, and time. This new being was said to be lovingly accepted into the arms of the others, and with them, they forged the first world. But, this was not to last, as this first world became the victim of Dauh's newfound insanity. Unable to comprehend its own vast form, it struck out against its creators in its existential dread, taking the world with it, shattering its form.

Eons saw the trio in conflict, the immature primal matter became their battleground, endless magics consumed. By luck, Oenui and Paerii gained the upper-hand in their conflict, shattering the form of Dauh, resulting in the seeding of the universe with their power. Time was fully established, as with death, and chance. But this victory was not to last, out of the remains of Dauh came numerous smaller beings, each an aspect of the primordial that came before them. These were a new unavoidable constant.

To save the universe from more endless conflict, Oenui and Paerii sought to create a new stable world, from this came the Worldplanes. Oenui laid out the groundwork, while Paerii dotted them with suns. To shape and finalise the Worldplanes, they were left with careful subjects, the E'onu, demi-god children. The E'onu forged the sub-planes, their own realms to watch the Worldplanes from, to keep watch in protection from the Dauh'ji, the eldritch old gods.

Due in-part to the magical protective auras laid down by the E'onu and their creators, most minor Dauh'ji are doomed to collapse when placing foot on the Worldplanes, like small blackholes, they evaporate, requiring vast amounts of anima, life energies, to sustain their forms. To achieve anima-feeding, they lure in weak-minded magi using their magics to feed on them. But, why do the larger Dauh'ji chose to avoid attacking their rival's creation directly?

---

The Worldplanes are made up of layers. The base layer is where the races, and life generally dwells. The Thoughtscape is where life gather their mana from through meditation, and where adventurous, or stupid otherworldly beings like Dauh'ji have risked communing with the aforementioned Magi from.

The Dream is the land of the gods, the home of the E'onu, and their own children, the elemental tribune (embodiments of the elemental forces), and where the gods watch over the Worldplanes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For fear of death.

The Dauh'ji may be vengeful, but they are no fools. They know the E'onu keep a watchful eye, so any large attack would surely be recognized and countered before permanent damage could be done.

The Worldplanes are protected by the children of the primordial beings, those with the ability to create Dauh itself. Oenui and Paerii are still ridden with guilt over the destruction of their first, most sacred creation by Dauh, and thus the E'onu they have employed as sentries will alert them should a second destruction become imminent. Small attacks may pass below the radar, but little of substance makes it past them. If the Worldplanes are truly in danger, Oenui and Paerii will stop at nothing to ensure the Dauh'jii are destroyed.

### They are asleep.

Alternatively, the Old Gods entered a deep slumber upon their defeat, conjured by the Dauh'ji Time. They are in no rush to attack the Worldplanes, as they count Time, Death, and Chance among their ranks, three beings whose forms were not fully realized in the First Great War. For the Dauh'ji, victory is assured. They are simply waiting to awake.

### They have already won.

The Worldplane may have been created by the primordial gods, but now, it is governed by entropy incarnate. Every world Oenui ever forged will crumble, every creature into whom Paerii breathed life will wither. All of creation will succumb eventually to Time, Death, and Chance. Their attack is slow - but its success is inevitable. All worlds - including ours - are dying as we speak.

Comment: Say, do you think a combination of the three ideas could work? They fear for death, so they slumber in a half-asleep state, sending their own 'E'onu', their Dauh'ji minions to do their bidding, created within a pseudo-hivemind.

Comment: @McGerridae That would work, but it seems unhelpful if your gods exist outside of the concept of time. Why not just wait and let everything die? No active involvement needed.

Comment: Perhaps those of disorder desire some sort of 'activity', and possess a childlike behavior through toying with the Worldplanes.

Comment: Oh, secondly, what if these Dauh'ji are prone to infighting? Perhaps some have broken from this great sleep, and are causing chaos and *disorder* among themselves. Providing a slight distraction to keep the Worldplanes safe.

Answer (score 2):

**They don't attack it.  They feed on it.**

If I am able consume my prey entirely, I can attack and kill it, then consume it when it is no longer putting up a fight.  That works for lions.

If I cannot consume my prey entirely, and especially if my prey poses a risk to me because I may /collapse when placing foot on the Worldplanes/ then I need to be sneaky.  I cannot attack because I will be noticed.  I can feed if I am sly.  That works for ticks and mosquitoes.

The WorldPlanes as a whole are delicious but also very dangerous to magical entities.  The energy of such entities can be sucked up and incorporated into that of the plane.  To get energy off the plane these entities must work at the edges, gather crumbs and otherwise feed without being fed upon.